# In command prompt ionic keyword is working fine but not in Hudson

Tags: shell, jenkins, ionic-framework, command-line, hudson

In command prompt `ionic` keyword is working fine but not in Hudson.

[image: This is my normal command prompt. Working fine.]

I tried to add command `ionic build android` in script but the keyword `ionic` itself is not working. How to fix this problem.

[image: Hudson <code>ionic</code> keyword is not recognized. But <code>npm</code> keyword is working.]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Need to set the environment variables in system variable.]

i wrongly setup the environment variables in user variable section
so it works only in command prompt. but it not work in Hudson.

also i included a path in system variable path
as ;C:\Users\Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm;

Now works fine. after reading several websites and stack-overflow . i found this solution.